# Ошибка в Unity, связанная со скриптами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity выдает ошибку: **Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found** при добавлении скрипта в Inspector.
Не знаю, из-за чего эта проблема, ведь совсем недавно я пользовался этими же скриптами и не менял их Class и название.
При создании нового скрипта та же самая ошибка, пробовал установить новую Unity - без толку. Подскажите, что ещё можно сделать?
СКРИПТ (САМЫЙ КОРОТКИЙ):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkinBuy : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int priceCharacter;
}
```

ИЛИ ЕЩЕ СКРИПТ:

```
(ТЕ ЖЕ САМЫЕ БИБЛИОТЕКИ)

public class RotateCoin : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Start()
  {

  }

  void Update()
  {
    transform.Rotate(0, 60 * Time deltaTime, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Скрипт должен как минимум лежать в папке Assets  и файл должен называться ровно так же, как класс.

Comment: Имя и класс совпадают, скрипт лежит в Assets/Scripts

Comment: @TabascoGamedev в какой папке лежит скрипт неважно.

Comment: А почему `при добавлении скрипта в Inspector`, вообще то скрипт надо добавлять не на Inspector, а на Hierarchy?

Comment: Без визуального подтверждения всех слов - вряд ли можно быстро помочь. Нужно больше инфы с визуальным оформлением что где есть, что куда суётся и в какой момент где что высвечивается :))

Comment: Допустим, я кидаю скрипт на камеру. Через Hierarchy если надеть скрипт - вылезет окно с ошибкой, скрипт при этом не надевается. Через Inspector тоже можно, нажимаю на камеру, перетаскиваю скрипт в инспектор - вылазит ошибка и скрипт не надевается

Comment: Приведите здесь имя скрипта (прям выделите его и скопируйте, а **ни в коем случае не перепечатывайте вручника**), а также приведите здесь код этого самого скрипта. (правьте вопрос и добавляйте подбробности туда)

Comment: Например, скрипт SkinBuy, смотри в вопросе я его правил

Comment: В вопросе ничего нет.

Comment: Хм, посмотри ещё раз

Comment: И имена скриптов.... скопированные один в один (с расширением файла в т.ч.)

Comment: Все одинаковое. SkinBuy.cs и RotateCoin.cs